# Python xlsxwriter: как задать ширину колонок по максимальной длине текста в ней?

Tags: python, excel

Добрый день!

У меня есть excel файл.
Подскажите, как с помощью xlsxwriter раздвинуть столбцы по ширине, чтобы помещалась максимальная информация?

То есть например, в колонке {id, 1, 11, 111} ширина будет 3, в колонке {code, TEST, FILE, EXCEL} ширина будет 5 и т.д.

То есть сделать то же самое, как если выделить всю таблицу вручную и кликнуть по границе столбца.

Вопрос в том, как пробежаться по всем столбцам и установить нужную ширину?

Пример покажу на картинке:
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка на документацию: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#set_row
Примеры:

```
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 20)   # Column  A   width set to 20.
worksheet.set_column(1, 3, 30)   # Columns B-D width set to 30.
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)  # Column  E   width set to 20.
worksheet.set_column('F:H', 30)  # Columns F-H width set to 30.
```

Судя по документации нет простого способа "AutoFIT" (вписать размер ячейки по содержимому). Выход есть конечно, это считать длину для каждой ячейки и находить максимальную, и потом использовать её для установки ширины. Проще назначить "максимальный" и удобоваримый для глаз размер заранее. Например 20-25 знаков.

Выдержка из документации:

> There is no way to specify “AutoFit” for a column in the Excel file
>   format. This feature is only available at runtime from within Excel.
>   It is possible to simulate “AutoFit” in your application by tracking
>   the maximum width of the data in the column as your write it and then
>   adjusting the column width at the end.

Ссылка на пример AutoFit английский SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463274/simulate-autofit-column-in-xslxwriter

Comment: set_column я находила. Я вот за выдержку про autofit спасибо большое) Это именно то, что я хотела.

Тогда буду делать вручную. Пока не особо представляю, как пробегаться по всем ячейкам...

Comment: Сейчас профессионалы подскажут - код, возможно. Я если честно сам новичёк все методом тыка. Я думаю есть готовые решения в интернете (примеры скриптов) нарыл на английском SO пример возможно рабочий. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463274/simulate-autofit-column-in-xslxwriter (добавлю в ответ).

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую протестировать)

Comment: Не получается у меня использовать это решение.
Во-первых у меня много строк - по ним нужны вычислять максимальную длину. Во-вторых, у меня питон ругается на не закрытую книгу теперь О_о